# Kudu npm install failed

Tags: azure, npm, azure-web-app-service, kudu

I'm getting a very strange error when trying to deploy my project with kudu on Azure.

I have build my project with dotnet with VueJs. I have used the following template "https://github.com/MarkPieszak/aspnetcore-Vue-starter"

I have tried setting the WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION to a few different version now without any luck.

Here are the out from Kudu:

```
Command: "D:\home\site\deployments\tools\deploy.cmd"
Handling ASP.NET Core Web Application deployment.
  Restore completed in 735.88 ms for D:\home\site\repository\projectx.csproj.
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 15.9.20+g88f5fadfbe for .NET Core
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

  Restore completed in 345.52 ms for D:\home\site\repository\projectx.csproj.
  projectx -> D:\home\site\repository\bin\Release\netcoreapp2.1\projectx.dll
  projectx -> D:\home\site\repository\bin\Release\netcoreapp2.1\projectx.Views.dll
  NPM Installing dependencies...
  npm WARN package.json assert@1.4.1 assert is also the name of a node core module.
  npm WARN package.json buffer@4.9.1 buffer is also the name of a node core module.
  npm WARN package.json events@1.1.1 events is also the name of a node core module.
  npm WARN package.json indexof@0.0.1 No repository field.
  npm WARN package.json punycode@2.1.1 punycode is also the name of a node core module.
  npm WARN package.json querystring@0.2.0 querystring is also the name of a node core module.
  npm WARN package.json string_decoder@1.1.1 string_decoder is also the name of a node core module.
  npm WARN package.json url@0.11.0 url is also the name of a node core module.
  npm WARN package.json util@0.10.4 util is also the name of a node core module.
  npm WARN package.json vue-template-es2015-compiler@1.6.0 No repository field.
EXEC : npm ERR! error : Method Not Allowed [D:\home\site\repository\projectx.csproj]
  npm ERR!     at errorResponse (D:\Program Files (x86)\npm\1.4.28\node_modules\npm\lib\cache\add-named.js:260:10)
  npm ERR!     at D:\Program Files (x86)\npm\1.4.28\node_modules\npm\lib\cache\add-named.js:203:12
  npm ERR!     at saved (D:\Program Files (x86)\npm\1.4.28\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-registry-client\lib\get.js:167:7)
  npm ERR!     at Object.oncomplete (fs.js:108:15)
  npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this *entire* log,
  npm ERR! including the npm and node versions, at:
  npm ERR!     <http://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

  npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.2.9200
  npm ERR! command "node" "D:\\Program Files (x86)\\npm\\1.4.28\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "--ignore-scripts"
  npm ERR! cwd D:\home\site\repository
  npm ERR! node -v v0.10.40
  npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.28
  npm ERR! code E405
D:\home\site\repository\projectx.csproj(25,5): error MSB3073: The command "npm install --ignore-scripts" exited with code 1.
Failed exitCode=1, command=dotnet publish "D:\home\site\repository\projectx.csproj" --output "D:\local\Temp\8d65c86f4c7808a" --configuration Release
An error has occurred during web site deployment.
\r\nD:\Program Files (x86)\SiteExtensions\Kudu\79.11121.3655\bin\Scripts\starter.cmd "D:\home\site\deployments\tools\deploy.cmd"
```

Anybody who has a idea? The project runs fine on my computer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to your error information, your issue was caused by the incorrect Node version obviously. The one of the prerequisites of GitHub repo you used is `NodeJS >= 8.9.4`, but now it's `v0.10.40` on your Azure WebApp. As you said, the `WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION` setting has beed added, but it seems not work.

I followed the [document](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azureossds/2016/04/20/nodejs-and-npm-versions-on-azure-app-services/) to add the same setting and click `Save` on Azure portal as the figure below, then immediately my kudu console restarted and check my node & npm version which be correct.

[image]

[image]

So my suggestion is:

1. Please check your `WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION` setting whether be added in the correct field.
2. You can try to restart your Azure WebApp manually to make the change works.

Comment: Thanks! Still has some errors in the deploy script. But no longer this issue :)