# Azure deployment for ASP.NET Core with React fails

Tags: azure, continuous-deployment

I can manually deploy from Visual Studio by right-clicking the solution and choosing Publish.
But I want to make the process automated using Azure's app services.

I've done the setup process (connecting my GitHub repo with Azure app sevices).

But when I pushed to master, it takes some time then shows a failure.

Here are the last few lines of the log:

```
  npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.14393
  npm ERR! argv "D:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\6.9.1\\node.exe" "D:\\Program Files (x86)\\npm\\3.10.8\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "build"
  npm ERR! node v6.9.1
  npm ERR! npm  v3.10.8
  npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
  npm ERR! dotnetsyntaxtreevisualizer@0.1.0 build: `react-scripts build`
  npm ERR! Exit status 1
  npm ERR! 
  npm ERR! Failed at the dotnetsyntaxtreevisualizer@0.1.0 build script 'react-scripts build'.
  npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
  npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the dotnetsyntaxtreevisualizer package,
  npm ERR! not with npm itself.
  npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
  npm ERR!     react-scripts build
  npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
  npm ERR!     npm bugs dotnetsyntaxtreevisualizer
  npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
  npm ERR!     npm owner ls dotnetsyntaxtreevisualizer
  npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
  
  npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
  npm ERR!     D:\home\site\repository\DotNetSyntaxTreeVisualizer\ClientApp\npm-debug.log
D:\home\site\repository\DotNetSyntaxTreeVisualizer\DotNetSyntaxTreeVisualizer.csproj(37,5): error MSB3073: The command "npm run build" exited with code 1.
Done Building Project "D:\home\site\repository\DotNetSyntaxTreeVisualizer\DotNetSyntaxTreeVisualizer.csproj" (default targets) -- FAILED.

Build FAILED.

"D:\home\site\repository\DotNetSyntaxTreeVisualizer\DotNetSyntaxTreeVisualizer.csproj" (default target) (1:7) ->
(PublishRunWebpack target) -> 
  D:\home\site\repository\DotNetSyntaxTreeVisualizer\DotNetSyntaxTreeVisualizer.csproj(37,5): error MSB3073: The command "npm run build" exited with code 1.

    0 Warning(s)
    1 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:06:10.93
Failed exitCode=1, command="D:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild-16.4\MSBuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe" /restore "D:\home\site\repository\DotNetSyntaxTreeVisualizer\DotNetSyntaxTreeVisualizer.csproj" /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:configuration=Release /p:publishurl="D:\local\Temp\8d814f3bc2d7331"
An error has occurred during web site deployment.
\r\nD:\Program Files (x86)\SiteExtensions\Kudu\87.20522.4610\bin\Scripts\starter.cmd "D:\home\site\deployments\tools\deploy.cmd"
```

This the the [GitHub repo](https://github.com/Youssef1313/DotNetSyntaxTreeVisualizer/) in case it's needed.

Comment: Can you add your build tasks? that error it's that "use Node" is missing in your build.

Comment: @NachoMartínez-Aedo, I just linked the repo in the `Deployment Center` in Azure. I'm not sure of where and how to write these build tasks. I've recently added a CI pipeline that just runs "dotnet build". But I don't think it's relevant.

Comment: Yeah, the CI pipeline get your code and then execute the task and with the result of that tasks make the deployment. You are getting and error cause you don't specify the node that your code need. What pipeline do you use?? App Service build service, Github Actions, or Azure pipelines?

Comment: I'm using Azure's App Services. I was prompted to some option in the first-setup process and I've chose Kudu as build provider

Comment: I've changed Kudu to Azure Pipeline and it worked! Thanks @NachoMartínez-Aedo

Comment: Yeah, I was testing the kudu deployment cause a never worked with it before. The pipeline that you create on the repo worked then?? Perfect!

Comment: The problem you were having(node versions) is solved with this answer. maybe this will help someone else: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53676820/kudu-npm-install-failed